# What sports court is this, with a white circle inside a white square or triangle, and diagonal colored lines?

Tags: trivia, venues

I saw this sports court the other day and I can't figure out the rules for the game. I have no idea where I would even start looking.

Below are satellite images of the court. I've tried to trace one to make it more visible (there are more smaller lines that can't be seen but they appear to be minor).

[image: Drawn image outlining an unknown sports court]

[image: Satellite image of an unknown sports court, 1]

[image: Satellite image of an unknown sports court, 2]

[image: Satellite image of an unknown sports court, 3]

Comment: Personally it looks like a version of four square. Can you provide a link to the actual image you are looking at? Is this a school?

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's a sports layout? My first thought, on seeing the top photo, is that it's laid out on a car park, and that it might be something like an odd layout for a helicopter landing pad?

Comment: @TrueDub it's definitely for sports -- there is no way you could land a helicopter through those trees, and there are three of them.

Comment: @diggers3 This is in a church parking lot. Next time I'm there I'll post a picture. I thought four square at first but although it would work for that, there are way more lines than necessary.

Comment: What about tetherball? If there are 3 of them that would make  sense and the four quadrants for each player.

Comment: @PaulWitry There is no pole, or a space for one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an [Awana Game Square](http://awana.org/art-awana-gamesquare/) (your mention of this being in a church parking lot may corroborate this).

More information can be found at the aforementioned link, but as for rules:

> Teams stand outside the large square along the line of their team color. In relay games, the center pin and bean bag are placed on the very center of the circle. Each team member, in turn, runs from his starting pin, around the complete circle, past his starting pin and along his color diagonal into the center of the circle for the center pin or bean bag.